# C# Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'class1' and 'class2'

Tags: c#

```
        if (Inventory.Length == 12)
            chr.Equipment = Inventory.Select(_ => _ == null ? (short)-1 : _.ObjectType).ToArray();
        else if (Inventory.Length == 20)
        {
            short[] equip = Inventory.Select(_ => _ == null ? (short)-1 : _.ObjectType).ToArray();
            Array.Resize(ref equip, 12);
            chr.Equipment = equip;
            equip = Inventory.Select(_ => _ == null ? (short)-1 : _.ObjectType).Reverse().ToArray();
            Array.Resize(ref equip, 8);
            chr.Backpack = equip; 
        }
```

With this code I get the following error:

*Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'short' and 'ushort'*

Would be really kind if someone could atleast explain me what I did wrong

Comment: What is the type of the Equipment property?

Comment: Note that using `_` as a parameter is a convention to indicate that the parameter is unused, but you're using it.  Since you're using it you should really give it a different name, ideally one that indicates it's meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second and third operands to the conditional operator need to either be of the same type, or there needs to be an implicit conversion from one to the other.  You provided one operand of type `short` and one of type `ushort`, and there's no implicit conversion from either to the other.

If you happen to know that `_.ObjectType` will always fit into a `short`, even though it's a `ushort`, you can cast it (there's an *explicit* conversion).  If it won't, then you'll need to have the second operand be a value other than `-1`, as `-1` isn't a valid `ushort`.